# Как выставить тактовую частоту в Atmel Studio 6 для ассемблера?

Tags: atmel-studio

Как в Atmel Studio 6 в проекте на ассемблере выставить тактовую частоту?

Answer (score 1):

Самому стало интересно :D

«Как выставить частоту процессора в AVR Studio:
Запускай процесс симуляции. Только в этом случае появится нужный пункт меню. А потом лезь в меню Debug -> AVR Simulations Options.

Может это не то, я не знаю)

Comment: В Atmel Studio 6 все же видимо по-другому как то.

Answer (score 0):

Частота контроллера указывается при его прошивке:либо в виде команды для avrdude,к примеру либо просто конфигурацией фьюзов CKSEl в настройках вашего программатора,для встроенного тактового генератора,а уж если используется внешний тактовый генератор,тактовую частоту задает он.